# How to add file browser in interactive grid row - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to convert a field from an interactive grid in a file browser?. I really need to upload the files according to the rows that a table has configured

```
select descripcion, alias
  from documento_tipo dt
 where requerido = 'S'
union all
select dt.descripcion, dt.alias
  from documento_tipo_ramo dtr
  join documento_tipo dt
    on dtr.documento_tipo = dt.id
  join cia_riesgo ramo
    on dtr.ramo = ramo.id
  join riesgo r
    on ramo.riesgo = r.id
 where r.id = :P15_ID
```

If you can't, is there any other solution?, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to add file browse in an IG. Please follow the below steps as a work around.

1. Create a Modal Dialog page (example: Page 2)
2. Create a Hidden item in the page. This is to hold your Primary Key value. (example: P2_ID).
3. Create a link column in your Interactive Grid. On click, the link must redirect to the modal page (page: 2). Pass the value of the primary key from the IG to the P2_ID Item.  (Refer below screenshot).

[image]

4. Create a File browse Item in Page 2.

Then follow the steps in the below link to save your uploaded file.

[File browse Item uploading to BLOB column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272579/file-browse-item-uploading-to-blob-column)

Comment: Good evening, I try to try the recommended option however I have the following problem: One of my items on the main page (P15_SOLICITUD_ID) is loaded through javascript that executes a function in the database `$s('P15_SOLICITUD_ID',answer.idSequence);` but when I add it in the link builder (name: p4_solicitud_id, value: &P15_SOLICITUD_ID.) and run the modal it does not recognize it since the modal item comes out soft

Comment: I have asked a new question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322822/how-to-assign-the-value-of-an-item-loaded-by-javascript-to-a-modal-page-oracle),  maybe you can help me, thank you