# How to assign the value of an item loaded by javascript to a modal page - Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

Good evening, I have an item that fills up when I run a dynamic action Run Javascript code. This javascript code executes an ajax callback that executes a stored procedure that returns a value. This is the part of javascript code that assigns the value that the database stored procedure returns to the item:

```
apex.server.process('prc_pg15_registrar', {
    pageItems: ['P15_PRODUCTO',
                'P15_TASA',]
}, {
    beforeSend: function() {
        lSpinner$ = ic.apex.animation.showWait(event);
    },
    success: function(respuesta) {        
        let titulo = 'Solicitud creada';
        let html = '<center> Se creó la solicitud N° <b>' + respuesta.idSecuencia + '</b> </center>';
        ic.apex.message.showModal({
            icon: 'success',
            title: titulo,            
            html: html
        });
        $s('P15_SOLICITUD_ID',respuesta.idSecuencia);//assigning to item
    }
```

the value is loaded without problems in the item, my problem is that when I want to send this value to another page it does not assign it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The link is built with linkbuilder - that means the link is generated when the page is rendered and it will not pick session values. That is the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Did some research and I think what you need is documented in this blog: https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/  - there is a sample app and the "Open Dialog (with dynamic url)" example sounds exactly like what you're describing.